# How to specify the frequency of WS pings with Gorilla

Tags: go, websocket, rfc, gorilla

The [WebSocket RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) states that there are control frames for pings/pongs. In order to avoid writing application code as a keepalive mechanism, is it possible to specify the frequency of pings using Gorilla WebSockets?

Answer (score 1):

Because the application is responsible for sending pings with the Gorilla WebSocket package, the application has complete control over the frequency that pings are sent.

See the [chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) for an example of how to send pings and use them to detect dead or stuck connections.